# how can I access userprofile from another user?

Tags: django, authentication, user-permissions

I need some help when I create a user and user profile accordingly and when I try to access to any user by another user the request turns me on the request I work on not the real user, although, I'm using the slug to specify what the user I click on it maybe I can not explain what happens to me exactly for more explanation, please click on that video to show what I mean: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MzSo0ay2_Xk&feature=youtu.be

accounts app

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify

CHOICE = [('male', 'male'), ('female', 'female')]


class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True, blank=True)
    overview = models.TextField(editable=True, blank=True, default='You have no an Overview yet')
    city = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False)
    phone = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True)
    sex = models.CharField(max_length=10, default='male', choices=CHOICE)
    skill = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='You have no skills yet')
    logo = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', default='images/default-logo.jpg', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.user)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)


def create_profile(sender, **kwargs):
    if kwargs['created']:
        user_profile = UserProfile.objects.create(user=kwargs['instance'])


post_save.connect(receiver=create_profile, sender=User)
```

view.py

```
class ViewProfile(UpdateView):
    queryset = UserProfile.objects.all()
    template_name = 'accounts/profile.html'
    form_class = UpdateInfoForm
    slug_field = 'slug'
    slug_url_kwarg = 'user_slug'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('accounts:view_profile', kwargs={'user_slug': self.request.user.userprofile.slug})

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        user_prof = UserProfile.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
        context['user_prof'] = user_prof
        context['get_favourite'] = User.objects.get(username=self.request.user.username).favorite.all()
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user_slug = self.request.user.userprofile.slug
        self.object = form.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

profile.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %} {{ user.first_name }} {{ user.last_name }} Profile {% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    <!-- User Profile Section -->
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
<div class="profile">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="col-md-1">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <!-- Profile View Section -->
                        <div class="logo-image text-center">
                            {% if user.userprofile.logo %}
                            <div class="my-image">
                                {% if request.user.username == user.userprofile.slug %}
                                <a href="{% url 'accounts:user_image' user.userprofile.slug %}">
                                    <img class="img-responsive" src="{{ user.userprofile.logo.url }}">
                                </a>
                                <span>
                                    <a href="{% url 'accounts:add_avatar' user.userprofile.slug %}" class="fa fa-camera fa-1x text-center">
                                        <p>Upload Image</p>
                                    </a>
                                </span>
                                {% endif %}
                            </div>

                            {% else %}

                            {% load static %}
                            <div class="my-image">
                                <img class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" src="{% static 'index/images/default-logo.jpg' %}">
                                <span>
                                    <a href="{% url 'accounts:add_avatar' user.userprofile.slug %}" class="fa fa-camera fa-1x text-center">
                                        <p>Upload Image</p>
                                    </a>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                            {% endif %}
                            <h4>{{ user.first_name }} {{ user.last_name }}</h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <div class="caption">
                        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                            <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#overview" class="trigger" data-target="#overview">Overview</a></li>
                            <li role="presentation" class=""><a href="#personal-information" class="trigger" data-target="#personal-information">Personal Information</a></li>
                            <li role="presentation" class=""><a href="#my-skills" class="trigger" data-target="#my-skills">Skills</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Information Sections -->
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-3 information">
            <div class="overview show" id="overview">
                <h2 class="line">Overview</h2>
                <p class="lead">{{ user.userprofile.overview }}</p>
                <a data-placement="bottom" title="update overview"  class="fa fa-edit" data-toggle="modal" data-tooltip="tooltip" data-target=".overview_info"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="personal-info" id="personal-information">
                <h2 class="line">Personal Information</h2>
                <p class="lead">City: {{ user.userprofile.city }}</p>
                <p class="lead">Phone Number: 0{{ user.userprofile.phone }}</p>
                <p class="lead">Sex: {{ user.userprofile.sex }}</p>
                <a data-placement="bottom" title="update personal information"  class="fa fa-edit" data-toggle="modal" data-tooltip="tooltip" data-target=".personal_info"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="skill" id="my-skills">
                <h2 class="line">Skills:</h2>
                <p class="lead">{{ user.userprofile.skill }}</p>
                <a data-placement="bottom" title="update skills" class="fa fa-edit" data-toggle="modal" data-tooltip="tooltip" data-target=".skills"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- get all questions -->
        {% if user_prof.userasking_set.all %}
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-3 user_questions">
            <h2 class="line">All Questions You Asked</h2>
            {% for questions in user_prof.userasking_set.all %}
                <p><a href="{% url 'community:question_view' questions.ask_slug %}">{{ questions.title }}</a></p>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
        {% endif %}
        <!-- get favourites -->
        {% if get_favourite %}
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-3 user_questions">
            <h2 class="line">Favourites</h2>
            {% for fav in get_favourite %}
                <p><a href="{% url 'community:question_view' fav.ask_slug %}">{{ fav.title }}</a></p>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
        {% endif %}
    </div>

{% include 'accounts/information_form.html' %}

</div>
    {% include 'base_footer.html' %}
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

`self.request.user` refers to the **currently logged in user**. That is why you are getting the same result for all users.

To get what you want, you need to make the following change in your views:

```
    user_prof = UserProfile.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
```

But also, I'm not sure why you are using an `UpdateView` when you simply want to *display* objects? You should use `TemplateView` instead.

Comment: but I can not put self into user_prof because the method is out of the class!
I'm using UpdateView because I need to  edit some fields in the profile

Comment: You should have separate views for editing and displaying objects.

Comment: do you mean the error of view comes because I have to change the view from update to template and I have to separate each view away other?